# Saving view on gitk

Tags: git, gitk

How do you make custom views (created in the View->New view menu) persist across gitk sessions?

There doesn't seem to be anything related stored in `.gitk`. Is this impossible to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just save them using the GUI. There is a checkbox "Remember this view" .. Enable it.

`gitk` will write a line as the following to `~/.gitk`:

```
set permviews {{{View1} {} --branches {}}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's called `Remember this view` on my gitk version, and it's just next to the view name

Comment: @goncalopp Oh. I used a German version. It was just my best guess :)